# Jquery Navigation bar is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a navigation type of thing, in HTML and i've added following code for it 
HTML

```
<div id="sign-wrap">    <div  id="click-box" class="welcome">    
    <p class="welcome" id="name">Welcome Mr. X</p>    </div>    <div id="dropdown">
       <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Insight Pro</a></li>
            <li><p>Mobiles</p></li>
            <li><p>Cameras</p></li>
            <li><p>Laptops</p></li>
            <li><p>Settings</p></li>
            <li><p>Logout</p></li>
       </ul>    </div> </div>
```

JQ:

```
$("#name, #click-box").hover(function(){
    if ($('#dropdown').is(":visible")) {
       $('#dropdown').slideUp(1000);
    }
    else{
        $('#dropdown').slideDown(1000);
    }
});
```

when I hover at Mr. X `#dropdown` slides down but when I take my mouse to `#dropdown` slides up... please help

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have given `hover` event on two different elements. When one elements' hover event is invoked then it shows the menu and when you try to go to that menu the other elements' hover is fired which takes your menu bar up (slide up) *[You are doing the slide up and down based on the visibility, so for the second firing the div is visible which makes it slide up]*

Use `mouse enter` and `mouse leave` events
On mouse enter slideDown and on mouse leave slideUp
(And if it's not required to give event on two elements then preferably apply event on one element to prevent flickering effect *[if any]*)

```
$("#name, #click-box").mouseenter(function(){
       $('#dropdown').slideDown(1000);
});

$("#name, #click-box").mouseleave(function(){
       $('#dropdown').slideUp(1000);
});
```

Refer [mouse enter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouse leave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events

Hope this solves the issue

Comment: dude those are same thing you are just separating it into two different events :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
var hovered = false;

$("#name, #click-box").on('hover', function(e){
        $('#dropdown').slideDown(1000);
});

$("#options").on('hover', function(e){
        hovered = true;
});

$("#dropdown").on('mouseleave', function(e){
        hovered = false;
});

$("#sign-wrap").on('mouseleave', function(e){
    if(!hovered){
        $('#dropdown').slideUp(1000);
    }
});
```

And see [this jSfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/z7WLd/3/)

Comment: dude your code is working like charm, but the problem is when I hover on Mr. X and I don't go to dropdown window it doesn't slides up.

Answer (score 0):

Using a click event on the click-box element may make it a little easier for your users to click the menu items. For example you could use the following snippet

```
$("#click-box").click(function () { $("#dropdown").slideToggle("slow"); });
```

Hope this helps you some.